# Get url & parameters of a POST request made from an android app. (Hack an application)

Tags: android, security, http, post

1> Is it possible to fetch the end-point of a http post request made from an android app?

2> Is it possible to fetch the parameters (key & value) of that request ?

If it is not possible to fetch the exact end-point & the parameter list for a post request made from an android device, can we assume that it is very hard to hack that particular end-point?

Edit 1 :

Say, in my android app, I am using an end-point like - http://abc.xyz.com/buyItem with 2 parameters : itemCode=value1, price=value2

(how)Can the url, parameter list & values be fetched by a hacker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to monitor network traffic and get those values.

It is pretty easy to set-up with something like a basic (cheap) network hub (not a switch) and a PC attached and a few network tools like [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [`ngrep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngrep).

A `tcpdump` example would be:

```
tcpdump -A -i eth3 > t.dump
```

Change `eth3` to your network interface. You can look over the file `t.dump` in a text editor or use `less` or `more`.

**NOTE:** SSL / HTTPS connections are encrypted, so `tcpdump` will only give you parameters over HTTP.

There are other ways as well.

You could get lucky and simply unpack the `apk` and `grep` for something like `://`. For example

```
grep -R '://' ./unpacked-apk/*
```

**Update:** Added a `tcpdump` example.

Comment: How to get the parameters from tcpdump ?

Comment: @Swas_99 Added a `tcpdump` example.

Comment: so if the connection is not SSL/HTTPS, the end-points can be hacked easily and the hacker can keep filling the database with garbage data or any other data of their choice?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Fiddler for this purpose, it is a tool that has a nice UI and you would not need to write any complicated command line commands. [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) is a documentation article on how to configure Fiddler to capture traffic on Nexus device.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the exact end-points, parameter list & their values by using Fiddler ?

Comment: yes, it is. it's a web proxy, so it captures web request/response with all the data

Comment: web != android app